# Can I sort Lucene results while using a custom collector?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Is it possible to sort Lucene results when using a custom collector, or would I have to implement that functionality myself, in the collector object?  I can't find an overload of IndexSearcher.Search that allows me to pass in both my own collector object *and* a sort field.

Lucene.Net, v2.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement the sort yourself. But Lucene.Net has an abstract class `PriorityQueue` that can be used in custom collectors (it is used internally in Lucene.Net while sorting (instead of collecting all results and then applying a sort on them) )

```
public class MyQueue : Lucene.Net.Util.PriorityQueue<int>
{
    public MyQueue(int MaxSize) : base()
    {
        Initialize(MaxSize);
    }

    public override bool LessThan(int a, int b)
    {
        return a < b;
    }
}

int queueSize = 3;
MyQueue pq = new MyQueue(queueSize);
pq.InsertWithOverflow(1);
pq.InsertWithOverflow(9);
pq.InsertWithOverflow(8);
pq.InsertWithOverflow(3);
pq.InsertWithOverflow(5);

int i1 = pq.Pop();
int i2 = pq.Pop();
int i3 = pq.Pop();
```

Comment: Perfect. Confirmed my suspicions. Thank you.